# how to connect to TFS visual studio code

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

I want to user `tfvc` with `visual studio code`, so install `Azure Repos` but when i want to connect i get this error:
[image]

after that i change my workspaces like this:
[image]

but i get same error.(open and close vs code, reinstall Azure Repos and delete and recreate workspaces none of them not working)

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in Github which is related to your problem.

Finally, I got the place to solve the issue at [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/issues/325#issuecomment-357871328)(worth to try)

1. Open Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017
2. Navigate to the workspace root folder
3. Enter "tf workspace"
4. Login

[Open Issue in Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-repos-vscode/issues/325)